# Why is this MySql Combined Unique Key not working?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySql table created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `sourcelinks` (
   `idSourceLinks` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `SrcId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
   `LinkId` int(11) DEFAULT '-1',
   `ImageId` int(11) DEFAULT '-1',
   `DownloadId` int(11) DEFAULT '-1',
   `VideoId` int(11) DEFAULT '-1',
    PRIMARY KEY (`idSourceLinks`),
    UNIQUE KEY `idSourceLinks_UNIQUE` (`idSourceLinks`),
    UNIQUE KEY `UniqueCombination` (`SrcId`,`LinkId`,`ImageId`,`DownloadId`,`VideoId`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=491 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

As you can see I have a combined UNIQUE INDEX over SrcId, LinkId, ImageId, DownloadId, and VideoId. Now my understanding is that if SrcId and LinkId have the same values as another row then a DUPLICATE INSERT exception would be thrown. That would be the same as SrcId and ImageId, or SrcId and DownloadId etc.

QUESTIONS:

1. So, why does it not actually work? I am getting multiple columns with the same values, that is multiple SrcId =1 and LinkId = 1 with the other columns in the index being null?
2. And how do i fix it so that each row can only have unique values attached for the columns

Comment: If ```PRIMARY KEY (`idSourceLinks`)``` is defined then additional ```UNIQUE KEY `idSourceLinks_UNIQUE` (`idSourceLinks`)``` (by the same field) is excess - primary key provides uniqueness already.

Comment: @Akina thanks for the information, but it does not actually answer the question.

Comment: Of course. But you must take this into account. About answer - Tim gives you the answer already.

Comment: Just curious... How did it come to be int(10)?

Comment: @Strawberry that is the default for MySql Workbench. I must change it! :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A unique index on `(SrcId, LinkId, ImageId, DownloadId, VideoId)` only means that a given combination of values of all five of these columns must be unique.  It does not that more than one record cannot have the same values for `SrcId` and `LinkId`.  If you require that, the unique index should be on `(SrcId, LinkId)`.  If this were the original intention of the five column unique index, then perhaps remove it and replace it with the two column version.

Comment: That is what I thought it meant, yet I am still getting duplicate entries in the rows.

Comment: @DaveGordon That's not possible if you really added the two column unique index.

Comment: @DaveGordon Before adding new unique index by 2 fields you must check your data and remove duplicates by this fields pair if they exists - or the index creation will fail.

Comment: It was the unique 2 column index that fixed it. Thanks @TimBiegeleisen